# Yii: combination of CDbCommand and ActiveRecord queries in one Controller/Action

Tags: sql, activerecord, coding-style, yii, many-to-many

I was wondering if it is a good (acceptable) practice to combine those to ways of retrieving/updating database data?

For example, in my database I have two tables (`Books` and `Users`) and one "many-to-many" table `Books_Users`. When a user rates a book, the `Books_Users` table should be updated (a new record with a `book_id` and a `user_id` should be whether inserted or deleted).

I googled ways of doing it using AR methods only, but I haven't found any good solution. I ended up using `CDbCommand` `execute()` and very simple SQL-query like `INSERT INTO books_users(book_id, user_id) VALUES(:bid , :uid);` in a `BookController` action.

The point is that all my models extend `CActiveRecord`, and I use AR methods all the way.

So here is the question: is that kind of blending of different approaches could be used without remorse, or I should get rid of it immediately and write the code in some "proper way"?

Answer (score 0):

Yii does support `Many_TO_Many` relations (to some degree) and this support has been improving through the 1.1.x releases http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/database.arr.

Generally i don't think you will have to use `CDbCommand` & get dirty with SQL, you shouldn't face any problems doing it with **AR** specially the **retrieval** part, However, **Insertion** (Create/Update) Could be a problem (not a huge one though) since it can be solved with some triggers either on database level (database triggers) or App level (Model `afterCreate()` & `afterUpdate()`) to automate populating/updating the middle table (pivot) records.

Another (cleaner) way would be to use this extension: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/cadvancedarbehavior/ which should do the job for you.

Last thing: take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481201/yii-framework-many-to-many-relationships) question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227361/yii-many-to-many-relationships) one for related inquires.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I saw the extension and the links before, but with no result. Yes, I don't have problems with retrieval, but I don't actually need to update the **models**. All I need is to insert or delete a row into a relation table. Honestly, I've just tried the extension, it doesn't work. `$book->save()` always fails and returns false. I had to return the CDbCommand. It's sad that I don't have much time to dig deeper (as I'm an Yii newbie I'll need plenty of time), but I hope to get beck to the problem later...

Comment: well, i still think investing in fixing your problem with the extension (& you should add related details to the Q, if you choose so) is better than investing in making a monkey patching with `CDbCommand` but its your choice!!